# How to trigger an event when a component is shown when using react-native-navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react-native with react-native-navigation. I would like to reload data when a component is shown. The component is shown when a user clicks on a tab navigation button.

Should I use react life cycle events or is there something in react-native-navigation that can trigger a function when a user navigates back to a component?

I am using redux, I am not sure if that could be used to help?

This issue refers to `onDisplay` which seems like what I am looking for. However I can't find any official documentation about it - https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/130

Comment: Basically attached custom event lets say  'loaded' to elements and trigger event loaded when ever needed

Comment: Yes, but how do I know when the component is being displayed?

Comment: I am not familiar in react. May this link helps you http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/03/24/best-practices-for-component-state-in-reactjs.html

Comment: Thanks but this is to do with react-native and react-native-navigation so I don't think that helps...

Comment: @ChrisF Can you please restore the answer you deleted here? Had I seen it, it would have saved me hours of time I wasted before I stumbled on that GitHub PR the answerer linked to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

include this as 'callIfBackToThisRoute'...

```
export default ( props, call ) => {
    if( !props.navigation ) throw 'I need props.navigation'
    const thisRoute = props.navigation.state.routeName;
    props.navigation.addListener(
        'willFocus',
        payload => {
            if( payload.state.routeName == thisRoute) call(props)
        }
    );
}
```

and use it inside your component...

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { doIt } = this.props;
    doIt()
    callIfBackToThisRoute(
        this.props,
        (props) => doIt()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 43):

I like the solution proposed by Bruno Reis. I tweaked mine to make it a bit simpler.

```
class Whatever extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.load()
        this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.load)
    }
    load = () => {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not currently seem to work (as far as I can tell). The new way to do this as shown in the documentation is: `this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', payload => {this.load()});` (taken from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle )

Comment: Works for me with Expo 33.0.7. Simple and effective, thanks

Comment: Wow I can't believe it works as easily as this, made my day! @dctucker How did you figure it out though? I mean, where did you find out about 'willFocus'?

Comment: This answers gives a solution that works with react-navigation, not react-native-navigation as asked by OP :/ See Stephen Liu and my answers bellow for RNN solutions.

Comment: saved my day! react navigation is tough... But you seem to have cracked it!

Answer (score 7):

In the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/), it shows that you can add a focus event like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const MyComponent = ({ navigation }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            // do something
            console.log('Hello World!')
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>MyComponent</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 4):

For RNN v3, after trying out for quite a couple times, I finally figured out the correct way:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.navigationEventListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.navigationEventListener) {
      this.navigationEventListener.remove();
    }
  }

  componentDidAppear() {   // Lazy loading data for RNN
    if (this.state.routes.length === 0) {
      this.getData();
    }
  }
```

The key is that, the binding of event listener is mandatory, otherwise the componentDidAppear() and componentDidDisappear() won't be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using:

```js
export default class RootNavigator extends React.Component {
  state = {currentScreen: null}

  _onNavigationStateChange(prevState, newState, action) {
    // const currentScreen = getCurrentRouteName(currentState)
    // const prevScreen = getCurrentRouteName(prevState)
    // console.debug('onNavigationStateChange currentScreen=', currentScreen,
    //   'prevScreen=', prevScreen, 'action.routeName=', action.routeName)
    console.debug('onNavigationStateChange action.routeName=', action.routeName)
    this.setState({currentScreen: action.routeName})
  }

  render() {
    return <RootStackNavigator onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
      screenProps={{currentScreen: this.state.currentScreen}}/>;
  }
```

coupled with `componentDidUpdate()` on the screen (which may or may not perform something depending on the screenProps's `currentScreen`).

Note: I don't know what/where `getCurrentRouteName()` is and it gave error for me so I don't use it and use `action.routeName` directly.

See https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2371 and https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51#issuecomment-323536642 for more information and discussion.

Comment: This is for react-navigation. The question was for react-native-navigation

Comment: Aha! I wasn't even aware of that distinction! Since I was also using React Native I thought that was the same. Sorry about it. Naming is the hardest problem in computer science, indeed. :)

Answer (score 2):

i have faced the same situation in one of my own project and use the **useFocusEffect** hook by react navigation to solve it

for more info you can  refer to the docs about this

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook

Comment: this is a different library

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer suggests a react-navigation solution, not react-native-navigation (RNN), so I'll go ahead and give my two cents.

As Stephen Liu points out in his answer, RNN provides [screen lifecycle methods](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Usage?id=screen-lifecycle) that fire when a component appears (`componentDidAppear`) and disappears (`componentDidDisappear`).

Stephen's answer works for a class component, however in the age of hooks I prefer function components. So this is how to use RNN's screen lifecycle methods in a function component:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation'

const MyComponent = ({ componentId }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const navListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this, componentId)

    // remove the listener during cleanup
    return () => {
      navListener.remove()
    }
  }, [componentId])

  this.componentDidAppear = () => {
    // do stuff when component appears
  }

  this. componentDidDisappear = () => {
    // do stuff when component disappears
  }

}
```

**Important**: `MyComponent` needs a `componentId` prop, which is injected automatically if it's a registered RNN screen or modal (`Navigation.registerComponent`). You can also manually pass it down from a screen component to the child where you need it.

**Bonus: `useComponentDidAppear` hook**

I use RNN's componentDidAppear fairly often in my project, so I made a custom hook to reuse it super easily throughout my function components:

```js
export const useComponentDidAppear = (componentId, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const navListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this, componentId)
    return () => {
      navListener.remove()
    }
  }, [componentId])

  this.componentDidAppear = () => {
    callback()
  }
}

// then use it like this
const SomeScreen = ({ componentId }) => {

  useComponentDidAppear(componentId, () => {
    // do stuff when the component appears!
  })

}
```

Comment: Sadly does not work `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "componentDidAppear", _this is undefined`

Answer (score -4):

Override componentWillMount lifecycle method:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount
Or just put the functionality inside render method

Comment: Thanks but this does not meet my needs. I would like an event handler to be triggered every time the user navigates back to a screen.

Comment: You can try doing it inside render method instead then

Comment: The render method does not get called when I click on the tab navigation.

Comment: The user can't see it, if they have clicked onto a different tab. Tabs are shown in this example - https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/example/src/app.js

Comment: If a user clicks on on tab, then back again, then I want to reload data on the screen.

Comment: Need to get this too. Something like onFocus/onAppear/onShown or similar...